# Can you, or should you, credit your editor and people who helped you in any way aside from writing in your novels?

Tags: creative-writing, novel

Can or should you credit your editor and other people who helped you in any way aside from writing in your novels? Is there a place to do that in a novel?

I don't typically see a place where people who didn't co-author the novel, but helped you in some way or form are credited, and also I don't know how to format such a piece of information. Should you write their full names and tell your readers how they helped you writing the book? Any example of this?

Comment: This article was informative (if you're asking about self-published texts): ["Book Acknowledgement Crash Course: Tips, Examples & Guides"](https://gatekeeperpress.com/book-acknowledgements/)

Comment: Have you really never seen a book with a dedication, acknowledgements, foreword, or afterword?

Answer (score 2):

Co-authors go on the cover. And on the title page. Usually there is some kind of ugly power struggle over who goes first. This often results in... Well, maybe I should not go there.

Acknowledgements usually go in the front few pages some place. This will be a discussion you have with your publisher, probably through the editor employed by your publisher. Different publishers will do it different ways. Some will put it on a page by itself after the title page. Some will put it at the bottom of the title page. If there is other material to go in the front pages before the text of the novel starts, different publishers will put these items in different order.